# Python for loop skips iteration

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, bots, skip

So I've made a selenium bot which iterates through the list of territorial codes and send this codes to a search box into the website which changes the code into the city name which i then scrape in order to get a list of cities in place of list of codes. The problem is that when my for loop iterates through the list there are moments in which it "skips" the commands given and goes straight into the next iteration therefore I am not receiving a full list of cities. Some codes in the list are absent or unfit to pass into the website so I made exceptions for that situations.

```
import time
import pandas
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_driver_path = "D:\Development\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path)
driver.get("https://eteryt.stat.gov.pl/eTeryt/rejestr_teryt/udostepnianie_danych/baza_teryt/uzytkownicy_indywidualni/wyszukiwanie/wyszukiwanie.aspx?contrast=default")

# Get the column with the codes from excel sheet and redo it into the list.
data = pandas.read_excel(r"D:\NFZ\FINAL Baza2WUJEK(poprawione1)-plusostatniepoprawki.xlsx")
codes = data["Kody terytorialne"].tolist()


cities = []


iteration = 0

for code in codes:
    time.sleep(0.05)
    iteration += 1
    print(iteration)
    if code == "Absence":
        cities.append("Absence")
    elif code == "Error":
        cities.append("Error")
    elif code == 2211041 or code == 2211021:
        cities.append("Manual")
    else:
        # Send territorial code
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_TBJPTIdentyfikator"]').clear()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_TBJPTIdentyfikator"]').send_keys(code)
        # Search
        try:
            button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                                '/html/body/form/section/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/input')))
            button.click()
        except:
            button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                                '/html/body/form/section/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/input')))
            button.click()
        # Scrape city name
        city = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="body_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_GVTERC"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/strong'))).text.split()
        print(code)
        print(city)
        cities.append(city)


table = {
    "Cities": cities
}

df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(table)
df.to_excel("cities-FINAL.xlsx")
driver.close()
```

Here is a part of my console logs. As you can see, after indicating that the iteration number is 98 it skips to 99 where it works completely fine, printing the city and the territorial code. This problem occurs further into the loop but everytime it starts at iteration number 98. Territorial code related to this is not one of the exceptions.

```
96 <-- Iteration
2201025 <-- Territorial Code
['Kędzierzyn-Koźle', '(2201025)'] <-- City Name
97
2262011
['Bytów', '(2262011)']
98 !<-- Just iteration!
99
2205084
['Gdynia', '(2208011)']

**!Quick Note due to the answers! Here is the order of the print statements in the console. First: number of the iteration, Second: Territorial Code related to the iteration, Third: City Name**
```

Comment: What is the value of `codes[97]`?

Comment: Ya, one of the `code` checks at the top must be being triggered, which causes the rest of the prints to be skipped, unless there's something else missing from this code.

Comment: Why do you have the same code in the "try" and in the "except"??? If the code fails at "try" it will fall again at except... Maybe it is failing at iteration 98.

Comment: Although, if it's failing a second time, that should cause an uncaught exception; unless this code is actually wrapped in a `try` that's swallowing errors.

Comment: So the value of the codes[97] is 2262011.  I have the same code in try except because sometimes selenium failed due to the "stale element exception" and couldn't  press the search button so if it fails then it tries again so technically if there was a failure and selenium couldn't find the button it should raise the error and stop the loop.

Comment: Please see my answer, I hope this will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. Your locators are terrible.
2. I see your results are not correct. For example for the "2262011" input the output is "Gdynia (2262011)" while you are presenting this output for the input "2205084"
3. Your except code is similar to the try code. This doesn't make sense. If that didn't work in try block, why do you think this will work at the second attempt without any change?
4. It is also preferably to wait for element visibility rather to presence since in the moment the element just becomes presented it is still not completely ready to be clicked on etc.
5. It's also better to keep elements locators at least on the top of the class, not hardcoded inside the code.

I tried to make your code little bit better.
Please try it.

```
import time
import pandas
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_driver_path = "D:\Development\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path)
driver.get("https://eteryt.stat.gov.pl/eTeryt/rejestr_teryt/udostepnianie_danych/baza_teryt/uzytkownicy_indywidualni/wyszukiwanie/wyszukiwanie.aspx?contrast=default")

# Get the column with the codes from excel sheet and redo it into the list.
data = pandas.read_excel(r"D:\NFZ\FINAL Baza2WUJEK(poprawione1)-plusostatniepoprawki.xlsx")
codes = data["Kody terytorialne"].tolist()

code_input_xpath = 'body_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_TBJPTIdentyfikator'
search_button_xpath = '//input[@id="body_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_BJPTWyszukaj"]'
city_xpath = '//table[@id="body_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_GVTERC"]//td/strong'



cities = []


iteration = 0

for code in codes:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    iteration += 1
    print(iteration)
    if code == "Absence":
        cities.append("Absence")
    elif code == "Error":
        cities.append("Error")
    elif code == 2211041 or code == 2211021:
        cities.append("Manual")
    else:
        # Send territorial code
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(code_input_xpath).clear()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(code_input_xpath).send_keys(code)
        # Search
        button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,search_button_xpath)))
            button.click()        
        # Scrape city name
        time.sleep(2)
        city = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, city_xpath))).text.split()
        print(code)
        print(city)
        cities.append(city)


table = {
    "Cities": cities
}

df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(table)
df.to_excel("cities-FINAL.xlsx")
driver.close()
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for answer. I am aware that some results are incorrect i had to lower the sleep time from 4 seconds to 0.05 and therefore it creates this whole "code not correctly related to the city" mess due to the fact that I wanted to test the code quicker becuase it failed in a same way even with the sleep time increased. I implemented the try, except method in such a bizzare way because the selenium was sometimes raising a "no stale element exception", and I've read that running the problem raising code twice using such notation may solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advices. You have to forgive me for the mess in my code, I'm still a newbie but this will surely help me to improve.

Comment: Sure, Ok, but did you try to use this code?

Comment: There is a problem with your change in my code. You didn't finish the try, except statement and the code doesn't want to execute itself.

Comment: You are absolutely right, sorry. I removed the try since there is no except there. 
Maybe I'm wrong, but again, since your except tried again what didn't work in try I simply removed the except and since there is no except try is removed too

Comment: This makes sense! Let me know if that resolved the problem

Comment: Ok, here's a little problem. '1
2262011
['Gdynia', '(2262011)']
2
2214011
['Gdynia', '(2262011)'].' As you can see wrong city is appended at the iteration number 2. Should be "Tczew" instead of "Gdynia". I think placing sleep right before the scraping part of the code should solve the problem because I think that it gives the div on the page time to load new information.

Comment: And I was right. Placing the sleep before scraping solves the problem.

Comment: Yes, because that element is already there before the click so immediately after click we just getting the old value!

Comment: It didn't work for the skip though. Still skips the iteration number 98. Maybe there is a problem with my Excel data?

Comment: I know you can't lol. I'm just asking from a technical point if there is a probability of such error if there is something wrong with Excel, but here you go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YJ2CWR3H2JwbuP7WU-VfIqm7GmGn3rdx4ZeutODvZdM/edit?usp=sharing  There are some cells written in a different language but they are the exceptions from the code

Comment: Well, right, no data found for "2211041" code. So our code looks correct.

Comment: Okay I got it.  When the code finds one of the exceptions it was just appending and printing only iteration numer so that's why there was this illusion of skipping. But that still doesn't explain why I got the uncomplete list at first hand. I'll test your code and let know if it helped.

Comment: I don't see here where the iteration number is appended. You just print it to the console.

Comment: No, no. You got me wrong. The iteration number always gets printed becasue it's the first line of code in the loop, then we raise the exceptions, and if the code catches one of them, it only appends the exception name to the cities list but in our else statement which we can explain as "nothing is wrong" statement not only does it append the city name to the list but also prints the city name.